# drupal 7 modify taxonomy page with hook_alter_menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i want to change or modify all taxonomy pages i write this piece of code in template.php in my bartik theme but some weird things happens.

the $term argument in second function "bartik_term_page" is null.

what is missing?
and it sometimes an error like this

it gives an error. 
Warning: Parameter 1 to bartik_term_page() expected to be a reference, value given in menu_execute_active_handler() (line  path\includes\menu.inc).

```
function bartik_menu_alter(&$menu) {
    $menu['taxonomy/term/%']['page callback'] = 'bartik_term_page'; 
    $menu['taxonomy/term/%']['access arguments'] = array('access content');
}



function bartik_term_page(&$term){

    $voc = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($term->vid);
    var_dump( $term ); die();

      // here you generate the actual content of the page
      // could be done e.g. with an entityfieldquery as follows

      $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
      $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
              ->fieldCondition('field_category', 'tid', $term->tid);
      $result = $query->execute();
      if (!empty($result['node'])) {
        $build['content']['nodes'] = node_view_multiple(node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node'])), 'teaser'); // output the node teasers. you can control the markup of the 'teaser' view mode with a template in the theme folder
      } else {
        $build['content']['status']['#markup'] = t('No results found for term ID !tid.', array('!tid' => $term->tid));
      }
      return $build;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually introducing a new router item there instead of overriding the existing one.

The path for the taxonomy page is `taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term`, so...

```
function bartik_menu_alter(&$menu) {
  $menu['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = 'bartik_term_page'; 
  $menu['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['access arguments'] = array('access content');
}
```

Clear caches and you should be good to go.

Comment: it gives an error. 
Warning: Parameter 1 to bartik_term_page() expected to be a reference, value given in menu_execute_active_handler() (line  path\includes\menu.inc).

Comment: Just don't accept the argument by ref, problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line after the 'page callback' line in your bartik_menu_alter() function:

```
$menu['taxonomy/term/%']['page arguments'] = array(3);
```

This tells Drupal where to find the parameter in your URL (it's the third component).

Comment: It would be 2 instead of 3 (the path parts are counted from zero), but it's not necessary anyway. `taxonomy_menu()` already sets it to 2

Comment: it gives an error. 
Warning: Parameter 1 to bartik_term_page() expected to be a reference, value given in menu_execute_active_handler() (line  path\includes\menu.inc).